# How to use $maybe in hamlet

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

In Yesod, I've got a form that populates the type

```
data Field = Field Text Text text
  deriving Show
```

When I write the hamlet html to display it, I'm running into the problem that Field is wrapped up in Maybe `Maybe Field`.  So in hamlet I'm trying to do the following as shown [here](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates)

(Snippet in postHomeR function)

```
let fieldData = case result of
      FormSuccess res -> Just res
      _               -> Nothing
```

(In the hamlet file)

```
<ul>
  $maybe (Field one two three) <- fieldData
  <li>#{show one}
```

However, when compiling there is `Not in scope: one` error.  Why is the variable one not created/populated correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to indent the <li> so that it's inside the $maybe block. As it sits now, it's a sibling to the $maybe, and thus the variables bound by $maybe are not in scope.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I actually just found that out just now too.